# Importing class from another file in python - I know the fix, but why doesn't the original work?

Tags: python, file, class, import

I can make this code work, but I am still confused why it won't work the first way I tried.

I am practicing python because my thesis is going to be coded in it (doing some cool things with Arduino and PC interfaces). I'm trying to import a class from another file into my main program so that I can create objects. Both files are in the same directory. It's probably easier if you have a look at the code at this point.

```
#from ArduinoBot import *
#from ArduinoBot import ArduinoBot
import ArduinoBot

# Create ArduinoBot object
bot1 = ArduinoBot()

# Call toString inside bot1 object
bot1.toString()

input("Press enter to end.")
```

Here is the very basic ArduinoBot class

```
class ArduinoBot:

def toString(self):
    print ("ArduinoBot toString")
```

Either of the first two commented out import statements will make this work, but not the last one, which to me seems the most intuitive and general. There's not a lot of code for stuff to go wrong here, it's a bit frustrating to be hitting these kind of finicky language specific quirks when I had heard some many good things about Python. Anyway I must be doing something wrong, but why doesn't the simple 'import ClassName' or 'import FileName' work?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: actually 'import FileName' works, as long as the file is in you $PYTHONPATH.

Comment: This isn't "finicky" at all.  In the first case, you are importing the entire namespace of the module into the local namespace.  In the second, you import a single class from the module namespace in to the local namespace.  In the third, you import the module itself in to the local namespace, so accordingly, you have to access its members as members of it.  It would probably be clearer if you didn't name your files identically to your classes (that's a Java thing, really), perhaps something like `arduino_lib`.

Comment: @sr2222 -- I typically avoid naming classes after the modules they're in too, but there's precedent for it in at least 1 stdlib module (`datetime`)

Comment: @mgilson Well, if there's one thing you can rely on working with Python, there will be at least one exception that proves every rule, and usually in the core distribution to boot.  :)

Comment: @sr2222 -- Yeah, another that kills me is `defaultdict`.  Really?  Not `DefaultDict`?  C'mon!  What about PEP8?  (especially when `OrderedDict` and `Counter` exist in the same module!)

Answer (score 5):

consider a file (`example.py`):

```
class foo(object):
    pass

class bar(object):
    pass

class example(object):
    pass
```

Now in your main program, if you do:

```
import example
```

what should be imported from the file `example.py`?  Just the class `example`?  should the class `foo` come along too?  The meaning would be too ambiguous if `import module` pulled the whole module's namespace directly into your current namespace.

The idea is that namespaces are wonderful.  They let you know where the class/function/data came from.  They also let you group related things together (or equivalently, they help you keep unrelated things separate!).  A module sets up a namespace and you tell python exactly how you want to bring that namespace into the current context (namespace) by the way you use `import`.

`from ... import *` says -- bring everything in that module directly into my namespace.

`from ... import ... as ...` says, bring only the thing that I specify directly into my namespace, but give it a new name here.

Finally, `import ...` simply says bring that module into the current namespace, but keep it separate.  This is the most common form in production code because of (at least) 2 reasons.

- It prevents name clashes.  You can have a local class named `foo` which won't conflict with the `foo` in `example.py` -- You get access to that via `example.foo`
- It makes it easy to trace down which module a class came from for debugging.

consider:

```
from foo import *
from bar import *
a = AClass() #did this come from foo?  bar? ... Hmmm...
```

---

In this case, to get access to the class `example` from `example.py`, you could also do:

```
import example
example_instance = example.example()
```

but you can also get `foo`:

```
foo_instance = example.foo()
```

Comment: I guess it's just a different way of thinking - to me, import FileX implies I want to import all the classes from that file. If they want to be explicit though, well it's not a huge deal at least I understand why it wasn't working now. Thanks.

Comment: from the zen of python (`import this`):  "Explicit is better than implicit".  If you want to be implicit, use `from ... import *`.  Each form of import is different -- If 2 forms did the same thing, that would be in conflict with the zen as well ("There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.")  Although, "that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch." ;-)

Comment: Why does that make sense?  The module itself is an object, an instance of the `module` class.  If importing a module imported all its component parts, you'd be giving up much of the benefit of the object-ness of the modules themselves.

Comment: @user1262553 The module system has nothing to do with the class system. It doesn't even bother to know what names in the module being imported are classes and which are not. Plus, your suggested system would make it impossible to get access to all the names in a module, but still have them in a separate namespace to avoid collision with local names (which is what the `import foo` form currently does).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that modules are things in Python.  A module has its own status as a container for classes, functions, and other objects.  When you do `import ArduinoBot`, you import the module.  If you want things in that module -- classes, functions, etc. -- you have to explicitly say that you want them.  You can either import them directly with `from ArduinoBot import ...`, or access them via the module with `import ArduinoBot` and then `ArduinoBot.ArduinoBot`.

Instead of working against this, you should leverage the container-ness of modules to allow you to group related stuff into a module.  It may seem annoying when you only have one class in a file, but when you start putting multiple classes and functions in one file, you'll see that you don't actually want all that stuff being automatically imported when you do `import module`, because then everything from all modules would conflict with other things.  The modules serve a useful function in separating different functionality.

For your example, the question you should ask yourself is: if the code is so simple and compact, why didn't you put it all in one file?

Answer (score 0):

Import doesn't work quite the you think it does. It *does* work the way it is documented to work, so there's a very simple remedy for your problem, but nonetheless:

```
import ArduinoBot
```

This looks for a module (or package) on the import path, executes the module's code in a new namespace, and then binds the **module object itself** to the name `ArduinoBot` in the current namespace. This means a module global variable named `ArduinoBot` in the `ArduinoBot` module would now be accessible in the importing namespace as `ArduinoBot.ArduinoBot`.

```
from ArduinoBot import ArduinoBot
```

This loads and executes the module as above, but does not bind the module object to the name `ArduinoBot`. Instead, it looks for a module global variable `ArduinoBot` within the module, and binds whatever object that referred to the name `ArduinoBot` in the current namespace.

```
from ArduinoBot import *
```

Similarly to the above, this loads and executes a module without binding the module object to any name in the current namespace. It then looks for *all* module global variables, and binds them all to the same name in the current namespace.

This last form is very convenient for interactive work in the python shell, but generally considered bad style in actual development, because it's not clear what names it actually binds. Considering it imports *everything* global in the imported module, including any names that *it* imported at global scope, it very quickly becomes extremely difficult to know what names are in scope or where they came from if you use this style pervasively.

Answer (score 0):

The module itself is an object. The last approach does in fact work, if you access your class as a member of the module. Either if the following will work, and either may be appropriate, depending on what else you need from the imported items:

```
from my_module import MyClass 
foo = MyClass()
```

or

```
import my_module
foo = my_module.MyClass()
```

As mentioned in the comments, your module and class usually don't have the same name in python. That's more a Java thing, and can sometimes lead to a little confusion here.